# ServiceStack.OrmLite: NullReferenceException in ServiceStack.Text.AssemblyUtils.ToTypeString(Type type)

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

As I continue testing out OrmLite, I ran into another problem, this one appears to happen in the ServiceStack.Text.AssemblyUtils:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ServiceStack.Text.AssemblyUtils.ToTypeString(Type type)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsWriter`1.WriteType(TextWriter writer, Object value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteListsOfElements`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.cctor>b__0(TextWriter writer, Object obj)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteListsOfElements`2.WriteGenericIList(TextWriter writer, IList`1 list)
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(Object value, Type type)
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.SerializeToString[T](T value)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.GetFieldValue(FieldDefinition fieldDef, Object value)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.GetValueOrDbNull[T](FieldDefinition fieldDef, Object obj)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.SetParameterValue[T](FieldDefinition fieldDef, IDataParameter p, Object obj)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.SetParameterValues[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, Object obj)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.Insert[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj, Action`1 commandFilter, Boolean selectIdentity)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.UntypedApi`1.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Insert>b__0(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at tWorks.Core.CoreServerCommons.Handlers.OrmLiteDbHandler.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<AddCoreObjectToDatabase>b__0(IDbConnection db) in D:\[GIT]\Core\CoreServerCommons\Handlers\DbHandlers\OrmLite\OrmLiteDbHandler.cs:line 253
```

It happens when I what to insert an object, using the Untyped API, like this:

```
long insertedId = dbCluster.GetDbAndRun((IDbConnection db) =>
{
    coreObject.Id = id;
    var typedApi = db.CreateTypedApi(coreObject.GetType());
    return typedApi.Insert(coreObject, selectIdentity: true);
});
```

The 'coreObject' I am trying to insert:

```
public class ModuleController : Actor
{
    public ModuleController(string username, List<Type> contactTypes)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.ContactTypes = contactTypes;

        this._AllowedLoginChannels = new List<Type>();
        this._AllowedLoginChannels.Add(typeof(CoreClient));
    }
    public List<Type> ContactTypes { get; set; }
}
```

I managed to figure out where the NullRef comes from:

[image]

Basically, if there is a `NULL` entry in the `ContactTypes` List, then it fails as above.

Now, in this case, the list shouldn't contain a `NULL` value, but I would feel a lot better if I didn't get a NullRef deep inside ServiceStack because of it, hindering me from persisting the object. Maybe I want a `NULL` there?

Is it just in List, or a Dictionary can't have `NULL` values either? What else cannot be `NULL` when persisting?

Shouldn't ServiceStack just handle it as null, so in its JSON format, that would simple be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite uses the JSV Format to serialize complex type blobs by default, it’s a white space sensitive that uses CSV Format by  which doesn’t include a `null` data type as that would be inferred as a “null” string, instead any null properties are simply excluded from the wire format which has the same effect as retaining the default property value when it’s deserialized.

If you want to include nulls in your serialized data you can [change the text serializer used to serialize complex types](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#pluggable-complex-type-serializers), e.g:

```
PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
```

Comment: CSV format? All i've ever seen of complexed blobbed data i JSON, not CSV, and JSON differentiates between `"null"` and `null`. And if it is excluded, why do I get a NullRef error? Shuldnt the 3d entry in the list simple be excluded?

Comment: Aha, "JSV" is your own thing, JSON + CSV i just read now. Why dont you differentiate between "null" and null? They are very different things; JSON has it correct - within quotes => `string`, without quotes => `null`

Comment: JSV is JSON with the CSV Format which results in smaller payload and better performance. JSV can’t express a null element and removing it results in a different object. Obviously having null elements is fraught with issues since it’s rarely guarded against when dealing with typed collections but you can switch to JSON if you need to.

Comment: I dont wanna mess too much with the standard, especially if affects performance, so let me ask this again:
_"And if it is excluded, why do I get a NullRef error? Shuldnt the 3d entry in the list simple be excluded?"_

Comment: There is no way to express a null value, JSV/CSV only includes quotes when values contain an escape character.

Comment: But, you wrote that "instead any null properties are simply excluded from the wire format". Shouldnt the 3rd entry, that is null in the list, be excluded? Instead, I get a NullRef error...

Comment: Because you’re serializing a collection with a null element, removing an element changes the data structure. Use JSON if you need to.

Comment: @Ted yes properties not elements, removing a property results in null, that’s not the same behaviour as removing elements. If you didn’t want a null element don’t save a collection containing one, if you do want a null element switch to JSON.